# Eclipse with php is not showing errors on missing file with require or include

Tags: php, eclipse, include, require

I just installed Eclipse to use it with PHP. I have a file with the content:

```
<?php 
    require 'content/addon.php';
?>
```

The problem is that the file `addon.php` doesn't exist yet Eclipse is not showing any warnings or errors.

Is there a way to configure Eclipse to show errors on files that are requested by `require` or `include`, but the file doesn't exist?

The example above is simple, but I'm going to work with a big website with hundreds of files and I want to find those missing requires without have to test all pages.

Comment: I don't think so, because Eclipse is (as far as I know) a Java-focused IDE. But a PHP-focused IDE like PHPStorm or IntelliJ IDEA with the PHP plugin give a warning if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: @chade_ the eclipse has already pointed a missing class that was on a different folder, away from my project folder. could be that hard to pointed a missing require/include?